# Returned mail setting in sendmail (Received-From-MTA is wrong)

Tags: email, sendmail

Mail server using sendmail+dovecot ,

I have a problem from returned mail system.

When I changed old_domain to new_domain.com,

smtp server works fine, but returned mail have wrong message:

```
The original message was received at Wed, 20 Aug 2014 09:24:41 +0800
from old_domain.com [xx.xx.xx.xx]

   ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<asdddxzx@gmsddf.vcom>
    (reason: 550 Host unknown)

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
550 5.1.2 <asdddxzx@gmsddf.vcom>... Host unknown (Name server: gmsddf.vcom: host not found)
```

this is error message in Mail Delivery Subsystem sent back:

```
Reporting-MTA: dns; new_domain.com
Received-From-MTA: DNS; old_domain.com
Arrival-Date: Wed, 20 Aug 2014 16:28:02 +0800

Final-Recipient: RFC822; asdddd@fma.ckfs
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.2
Remote-MTA: DNS; fma.ckfs
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550 Host unknown
Last-Attempt-Date: Wed, 20 Aug 2014 16:28:05 +0800
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer!
sendmail server uses Hostname setting and host setting

so make sure your setting is correct

1. /etc/hosts
2. /etc/sysconfig/network

and it works fine!

Comment: for example?  these files should say what?